# Trying to print an array of integers in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

I have been trying about 4 hours to print an array of integers.
Unfortunately, I didn't succeed at printing even 1 number in the array.
I have code that works 100% for one single number.

I tried in this code to print a single number in the array.
The result is very strange:

```
      32
```

The result suppose to be:

```
      2
```

because in the A array there is only the number 2 .

If I change these lines:

```
jge loopy
mov byte ptr[si],   '-'
jmp loopy
```

to:

```
 jge soff
 mov byte ptr[si],   '-'
```

it works, and the number 2 is printed. Something is wrong with the loop, even though the loop does nothing (because there is only 1 number) and only refers back to the `soff` label!

Of course I can find a code that do it on the Internet, but I really want to know what is going wrong in my code.

```
.model  small
.stack   100h
.data
A db 2
N equ 1
arrayCounter db 0

num  dw  ?
numS db  20 dup(' '),'$'
os dw ?


.code
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov di,offset A
    mov os,offset numS

    loopy:
    cmp cx,N
    je soff
    inc cx

    ; move the next number to print, to num value
    mov bl,arrayCounter
    mov al,[di+bx]
    cbw
    inc arrayCounter
    mov num,ax



    mov ax, num
    mov bx, 10

    mov si, offset numS+19

next:   cwd
    idiv    bx
    cmp dx, 0
    jge cont
    neg dx
cont:
    add dl, 48
    mov [si],   dl
    dec si
              cmp   ax, 0
    jz  sof
    jmp         next
sof:    
    cmp num,    0

    jge loopy
    mov byte ptr[si],   '-'
    jmp loopy


soff:
    mov ah, 9h
    mov dx, offset numS

    int 21h


    .exit
end
```

Comment: Under `loopy:` you have the line `cmp cx,N`, but you are not initializing `cx`. You have to do `mov cx,0` before `loopy`.

Comment: Also you only load `bl` but use `bx`. You could use `movzx bx,arrayCounter` to fix that.

Comment: thank you @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez ! now it works ! isn't cx 0000 by default? why I have to write mov cx,0 ?

Comment: You always have to give value to your registers.

Comment: Depends on the particular environment, but it's good practice to initialize your registers.